# Chart.js dynamically upating data using variable

Tags: php, ajax, chart.js

I'm trying to update my Chart (chart.js) using a variable as data (fetched using an Ajax response).

**Working** - when `$data` is added manually (not as a variable)

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getCountryData.php",
        data: {url: url},
        success: function(data){

            casesChart.data.datasets[0].data = ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','3','3','3','3','3','3','3','3','3','3','3','3','3','3','20','62','155','229','322','453','655','888','1128','1694','2036','2502','3089','3858','4636','5883','7375','9172','10149','12462','12462','17660','21157','24747','27980','31506','35713','41035','47021','53578','59138','63927','69176','74386','80589','86498','92472','97689','101739','105792','110574'];;

            casesChart.update();
        }

    })
```

[[image: working version][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ho5w.png)

However when I used my `data` variable from a PHP ajax response the outcome is completely different, but the formats are exactly the same.

**Not working**

```
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getCountryData.php",
        data: {url: url},
        success: function(data){

            console.log(data)
            casesChart.data.datasets[0].data = data    
            casesChart.update();
        }  
    })
```

[image: Contents of my data variable]
[image: not working chart]

Any advice or guidance in the right direction would be great, this one is lost on me!

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the updated chart is only the first values of your new data.

```
casesChart.data.datasets[0].data = data
```

It seems that the data and the labels are out of sync. You probably also need to update the `labels`. Their number should be identical to the number of values contained in `data`.

```
casesChart.data.labels = <new labels>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my particular case was that the array was being outputted as a string rather than a JavaScript object.

I was able to fix it with the JS Split String command using the comma as the delimiter which then after testing in console.log confirmed it was again an Array object.